# Append element before submit form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to hash my password on client side before submitting (I have my own reasons, I know what I'm doing) to the server. I am using jsSHA (it works, I alerted output) to hash the password.

I create a new element, assign the hashed password to it's value and append it to the form. But the form still doesn't submit it.

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.0.2/sha.js"></script>
 <form id = "form" name="form" method="post" action="verify.php" class="login">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username" style = "width: 350px"><br>
   Password: <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" style="width: 350px; margin-left: 3px;"><br>
   Remember Me: <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" class="loginbutton" onclick="submitForm();">
 </form>
```

**JS**

```
function submitForm(){
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var pwd = document.getElementById('pwd');
    var hash = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT", {numRounds: 1});
    hash.update(pwd.value);
    var hash = hash.getHash("HEX");
    var password = document.createElement("password");
    password.name="password";
    password.type="hidden";
    password.id = "password";
    password.value = hash;
    form.appendChild(password);
    pwd.value = "";
    form.submit()
}
```

**Sent params:**

```
username: user
pwd: ""
rememberme: "1"
submit: "Login!"
```

How can I `password: *some value*` to these sent parameters? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should your `document.createElement` use `input` as argument instead of `password`.

Comment: May I suggest an alternative solution? How about changing the value of the existing pwd input just before submitting? This way you wouldn't need to create an extra element and to remove the existing one. This, of course only applies as long as you're switching the page on submit. For AJAX verification you want the hidden element - but in this case you'd rather search for it instead of creating it.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Well I was doing it that way, but it iritated me because when I click on submit, the password changes from ********* into ************************************************ before the page reloads.

Comment: Right. nevermind the suggestion then. Your solution is just as fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `password` element instead of an `input` element with `type="password"`. Browsers only send data from form elements they know (input, button, textarea etc.) Furthermore you are setting properties on the element, but setting attributes is probably safer in terms of compatibility.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I will accept this answer as soon as I'm able to.